# Parameterized query for MySQL in RStudio

Tags: mysql, r, dbi, rmysql

I want to run a parameterized query in MySQL database from RStudio.

Like there is a table, say `TEST`, which contains name and age columns. I want to fetch data from TEST `where age > 30`. I can use `paste()` to build the query but I want the value 30 as a parameter.

So I was trying the below code :

```
> myQ<-dbSendQuery(conn,"SELECT * FROM TEST WHERE age > ?")
> dbBind(myQ,list(30))
> dbFetch(myQ)
```

But after the 1st line it is giving the below error :

> Error in .local(conn, statement, ...) :    could not run statement:
>   You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near '?' at line 1

Can anyone please help me on how to achieve this?

> Edit 1

I can achieve this using the below code, but I don't want this :

```
> age<-30
> myQ<-dbSendQuery(conn,paste("SELECT * FROM TEST WHERE age >",age))
> dbFetch(myQ)
```

Is there any way to achieve my requirement?

> Edit 2

See the screenshot below, for reference go this [link](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/DBI/vignettes/spec.html#_description_46)
[image]

Comment: See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50760450/parameterize-sql-queries-using-r-rodbc/50762205#50762205) duplicate

Comment: No, this is not duplicate, please read my question carefully. In that question, it is for SQL Server and I am using MySQL. And the solution uses paste(), I don't want paste().

Comment: `sprintf("SELECT * FROM TEST WHERE age > %s", 30)`?

Answer (score 2):

You may be using the legacy 'DBI' interface [RMySQL::MySQL()](https://cran.r-project.org/package=RMySQL) as your driver for [DBI::dbConnect()](https://cran.r-project.org/package=DBI). The error you got cleared up for me when I switched to the suggested [RMariaDB::MariaDB()](https://cran.r-project.org/package=RMariaDB) driver. Per your screenshot, the DBI docs do imply the RMySQL driver.